# Live system boots into initramfs shell

Tags: installation, boot, initramfs

I'm trying to install Kubuntu Saucy x86 on a rather old computer from an USB stick (USB legacy emulation enabled)
I also tried to boot Ubuntu Raring from DVD but getting the same problem:
The system boots into the setup menu (Something like this:)

```
        Kubuntu 13.10

        Start Kubuntu
   Check disk for issues
        Test memory
 Boot from first hard disk
```

When hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> on *Start Kubuntu*, the Plymouth boot animation shows up, but when I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, I only see lots of something like these:

```
/init line 7: Can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found
```

After a minute or so I get into the initramfs shell with the notification that no medium containing a live file system was found.
As I said, this happens both from DVD and USB. I've used both media to install (K)ubuntu on other systems and didn't change anything on that stick.

The installed Windows XP boots without problems.

Please help me to get Kubuntu running on this computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to boot a Lubuntu Raring stick. I'm going to install it and, if I decide to, install `kubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Installation succeeded!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the *floppy drive* in your **BIOS** - many people have resolved the same problem this way. First of all, disable the *floppy drive*, then boot from the USB again, wait 3-4-5 minutes when the boot animation shows up and the installer shoud start.

This can happen because of a bug from the **USB Startup Disk Creator**. If the above does not resovle the problem, you can try to put the ISO of **Kubuntu** with **UNetbootin**.

You can read more on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/500822

Comment: Disabling the floppy drive didn't do it. I already tried it. Waiting resolves in the initramfs shell. I'll try unetbootin